# DriveImage XML in 64 bit Task scheduler

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, task-scheduler, driveimagexml

I would like to use Windows Task Scheduler to make a backup with DriveImage XML.

The first problem, which I somehow managed to solve, is that Windows Task Scheduler will not run 32 bit programs if Windows is 64bit. So I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410491/i-need-to-set-up-a-task-to-run-a-batch-file-in-32-cmd-exe) article, and added `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`to the *Program/script:* in the *actions* of the task.

In Program/script I have added `%systemroot%\Syswow64\cmd.exe` and in the arguments I have added `/C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Runtime Software\DriveImage XML\dixml.exe"` This allows me to run DriveImage XML in Windows Task Scheduler, even if it is a 32 bit application.

But this is where it gets a little tricky. Now that I have added `/C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Runtime Software\DriveImage XML\dixml.exe"` how can I append the arguments used for DriveImage XML? I tried to use [this guide](http://www.overclock.net/t/707190/how-to-backup-your-windows-os-using-driveimage-xml) but it does not account for the "32bit in 64 bit issue"...

So if anyone can help me to setup DriveImage XML in Windows Task Scheduler I would be very grateful.

[image: Please see this picture for what I have achieved so far]

Comment: Perhaps try adding your DIXMl arguments within quotes, after is dixml.exe, ie: `/C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Runtime Software\DriveImage XML\dixml.exe dixlmargument1 dixlmargument2"`

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I should not have quotation marks on the end path. `%systemroot%\Syswow64\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Runtime Software\DriveImage XML\dixml.exe"/bc /tB:\\DRIVE IMAGES\\Windows10_maintenance_backup` solved it.